# What is an embedding in algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am taking a first (graduate level) course in algebraic geometry and I am trying to understand in what sense the Segre embedding is an embedding, but I am having trouble finding the definition of an embedding in this context. I haven't learned about schemes yet, so in particular, what is the definition of an embedding of varieties?

From the definition of embedding in other contexts, I assume that an embedding algebraic geometry should be injective, (probably) regular and a homeomorphism onto its image. Is this correct or are there other conditions?

**Edit:** Similar to this question: [Segre embedding](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198320/segre-embedding?rq=1), though I would like a precise statement of the definition of embedding.

Comment: In Algebraic Geometry, these type of notions are usually understood in terms of affine covers. So, a morphism $f:X\to Y$ is an embedding, if there is an affine open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $Y$ such that $f^{-1}(U)$ is affine and the induced map of co-ordinate rings $\Gamma(U)\to\Gamma(f^{-1}(U))$ is onto.

Comment: Since nobody explicitly addressed your question in the final paragraph, these conditions do not give the correct definition of embedding. The map $t \mapsto (t^2,t^3)$ from the affine line $\mathbf A^1$ to a nodal plane cubic curve satisfies your properties but is not an embedding.

Answer (score 0):

I would define an embedding in this case as a morphism of varieties which is an isomorphism onto its image, and this image can be written as the intersection of an open and a closed subset (of the target domain). This should agree in reasonable cases with what is also referred to as an immersion.